# wxWidgets create an app that lives on the desktop?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is it possible, using wxWidgets and C++, to create an application that will show on the desktop? What I mean, is that it would only display on the desktop, like Geektools, Rainmeter, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box.

You could try to get the HWND of the Desktop and create your own control in wxWidgets by deriving a class from wxControl or wxWindow and do the Drawing yourself. It is not that hard to do it :). You could even use wxHTMLWindow or wxWebConnect (3rdParty, based on Webkit) for that.

See GetDesktopWindow() for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504(VS.85).aspx

Assuming you are on Windows. You have to check for your WindowManagers Documentation on Linux yourself though. If you are using KDE, I would suggest to use QT directly or the KDE API. Same for Gnome.

It would be easier to use the corresponding os/windowmanager api for that though.

Hope that helps.